# Error: GET 404 (Not found) error for images, but the images are showing up fine

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http-status-code-404, mean-stack

I am creating a MEAN app with images in one of my models. When the page loads, the images *are* rendering fine on the page but in my console I am getting this error about them: `GET http://localhost:3000/%7B%7Bitem.photo_url%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)`  and in my terminal thats running npm and mongod: `GET /%7B%7Bitem.photo_url%7D%7D 404 1.999 ms - 2083`

I'm unsure what's causing this error, as on the front-end it seems to be fine. Any advice would be appreciated! Thank you!

```
 .controller("IndexController", [ "$scope", 'items', 
 function($scope, items)
   { $scope.items = items.items
     $scope.addItem = function(){ 
    items.create({ 
      title: $scope.title, 
      photo_url: $scope.photo_url, 
      maker: $scope.maker, 
      description: $scope.description, 
      price: $scope.price }) 
    $scope.title = ''; 
    $scope.photo_url = ''; 
    $scope.maker = ''; 
    $scope.description = ''; 
    $scope.price = ''; 
    $scope.upvotes = ''; 
   }
}]; 


 <h2>Style Review</h2> 
 <div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: '-upvotes'"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" ng-
    click="increaseUpvotes(item)"> </span> 
    {{item.upvotes}} 

    <p>{{item.title}}</p> 
    <a href="#/items/{{item._id}}"><img class="indexImage" src="
        {{item.photo_url}}" alt="item image"/></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I pasted the code in the next comment section. I'm new to SO and tried to tag you in it, but I'm not sure if it worked

Comment: %7B = "|"  and %7D = "{".  So if you were to rewrite the link it will be http://localhost:3000/||item.photo_url}}
That means you angular is not binding to html.  Some where the "or" condition is being applied as part of photo_url string.  Share your angular controller and your corresponding html template

Comment: controller: ` .controller("IndexController", [
  "$scope",
  'items',
  function($scope, items){
    $scope.items = items.items     $scope.addItem = function(){

      items.create({
        title: $scope.title,
        photo_url: $scope.photo_url,
        maker: $scope.maker,
        description: $scope.description,
        price: $scope.price
      })
      $scope.title = '';
      $scope.photo_url = '';
      $scope.maker = '';
      $scope.description = '';
      $scope.price = '';
      $scope.upvotes = '';
    } `

Comment: html:  `    <h2>Style Review</h2>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: '-upvotes'">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" ng-click="increaseUpvotes(item)"> </span> {{item.upvotes}}
          <p>{{item.title}}</p>

          <a href="#/items/{{item._id}}"><img class="indexImage" src="{{item.photo_url}}" alt="item image"/></a>

        </div>`

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure why it's not putting them in code blocks? I thought i'm supposed to use backticks like `code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Html - try using

```
ng-src 
ng-href
```

For example:

```
 <h2>Style Review</h2> 
 <div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: '-upvotes'"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty" ng-
      click="increaseUpvotes(item)"> </span> 
    {{item.upvotes}} 

    <p>{{item.title}}</p> 
    <a 
        ng-href="#/items/{{item._id}}"> <--- SEE HERE (ng-href)
    <img class="indexImage" 
     ng-src="{{item.photo_url}}"  <----- SEE HERE (ng-src)
     alt="item image"/></a> 
    </div>
```

See angular documentation [Angular 1 ng-src Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm think `%7B%7Bitem.photo_url%7D%7D` it's a bad address. 
Please check in `console.log()` url of image
`%7B%7` - its not mean about file name
`Bitem.photo_url` this is var I think
Please paste some code for this problem

Comment: in my index.html file the line that's calling the image: <img class="indexImage" src="{{item.photo_url}}" alt="item image"/>

Comment: in my models file for my schema: `in my models folder for my ItemSchema: var ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ title: String, photo_url: String, maker: String, description: String, price: Number, upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0}, reviews: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Review"}] })`

Comment: and the photo url: `photo_url: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0233/5133/products/Polished-Rose-Gold_Blush-Leather_1_335x335.jpg?v=1441941608"` @Bitmask